# MSDeploy from IIS7 to IIS6

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, iis-6, hudson, msdeploy

I am trying to do an MSDeploy using the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='package.zip' -dest:auto,computerName='servername',includeAcls='False' -verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -setParamFile:"package.SetParameters.xml"
```

The server it will be deployed to is a Win2003 server running IIS 6. When I run this command from a WinXP Hudson CI slave, it works just fine. However, running this on a new Win7 slave gives me the following error:

```
Error: (12/21/2014 12:59:17 AM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
Error: The metabase key '/LM/W3SVC' could not be found.
Error: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AxNative' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.AxNative.MetabaseGetBaseObject(String serverName, String userName, String password, IAppHostWritableAdminManager manager, Object& objectHandle)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.MetaKeyCommitItem..ctor(DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Boolean useInternalAbo, Boolean isReadOnly)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.MetaKeyCommitItem.GetInstance(DeploymentBaseContext baseContext, Boolean useInternalAbo, Boolean isReadOnly)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.MetaKeyProvider.get_CommitItem()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.MetaKeyProvider.DoesNodeExist(Exception& e)
Error: The library 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\x86\axnative.dll' could not be loaded.
Error: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
Error count: 1.
```

Any ideas? Please let me know if more info is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with MS Deploy installation on the destination win2003 server running IIS6 (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\Web Deploy was supposed to have a "2" folder for web deploy 2.0, instead it had a "1" folder) .

I just repaired (reinstalled) MS Deploy 2.0 and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error: "The metabase key '/LM/W3SVC' could not be found." sounds like the wrong provider is being used on the Windows 7 (iis7) destination because IIS7 doesn't use metabase anymore. IIS7 and above use a config model.

Here is a link on [**how to migrate a site from IIS6 to IIS7**](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7-or-above) which shows an example of using a package from IIS6 server and importing it to an IIS7 server.

The only difference I see in your example is that they are specifying a metakey provider on the destination and you are using "auto". Auto might work for IIS6 to IIS6 but perhaps you need to specify the metaKey provider (used for IIS6 sites or IIS6 to IIS7 migrations) as the destination provider.

Create the package example

```
msdeploy -verb:sync  -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/<<YourSiteIDHere>> -dest:package=c:\Site1.zip > WebDeployPackage.log
```

Deploy to IIS7 destination example

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=c:\Site1.zip -dest:metakey=lm/w3svc/<<YourSiteIDHere>> > WebDeploySync.log
```

If you are doing IIS7 to IIS7 migrations you'd want to use the [**AppHostConfig**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569080%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) provider instead. But the [**metakKey**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569088(v=ws.10).aspx) provider is what is specified from Microsoft for IIS6 to IIS6 or IIS6 to IIS7.

Comment: I am not deploying this to IIS7. Deployment is being done to an IIS 6 server from an IIS7 server. Thank you for your answer though - I've managed to solve this issue (I'll post what was wrong as an answer and close this question).